# Node scheduler not running on every day

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks

I have create a scheduler like

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    rule.date = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
    rule.hour = 15;
    rule.minute = 0;
    rule.second = 0;

    var timeEverySecond = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){});
```

But the problem is it run only once at 15 hour at first time but not on every day. But I have set day of week and date too. How can I create rule to run this code on every at 15 hour.

Comment: just `rule.hour = 15;` should be okay. No need to provide dayOfWeek, date, minute, second etc

Comment: Initially I give rule.hour only but it executes once and never again. So only I started to give remaining

Answer (score 1):

You can use node-cron.

```
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 */15 * * *', () => {
 // Do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using node-schedule module, to execute every 15 hours you can try following:

```
schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * *', function(){
     console.log("Executing by every 15 mins !!")
});
```

If you want to execute at 15th hour of day i.e. 3 PM on each day you can try following:

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    rule.hour = 15;
    rule.minute = 0;
    rule.second = 0;

var timeEverySecond = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

1*    2*    3*    4*    5*    6*

6* day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)

5* month (1 - 12)

4* day of month (1 - 31)

3* hour (0 - 23)

2* minute (0 - 59)

1* second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('your code!');
 });
```